# Displaying Results returned from Server in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Good day;
I am learning angularjs and i looked at the example found in the spring website http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/.
The problem is nothing displays on the view but using firebug, i can see that data is returned from the server.
Here is my controller

```
function AController($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/users').
        success(function(data){
            $scope.user = data;
        });

}
```

and my view

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AController">
            <p>Email is {{user.email}}</p>
            <p>password is {{user.password}}</p>

        </div>
```

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Oh and here is the data returned from the server

```
[
    {
        "email": "azy@yahoo.com", 
        "id": 15, 
        "isActive": null, 
        "password": "$6$rounds=93733$jj3PWiZjtc0yC1Ws$bCIpDORaYFUDD.8kRRGpV64rMqFFQgR9ujlQEeTSd4r/To1snucdg.fsy2Ovkz39tRpy18ZWQnN7dKomdapKx."
    }, 
    {
        "email": "abd@yahoo.com", 
        "id": 16, 
        "isActive": null, 
        "password": "$6$rounds=100762$uSVOZI5oPAtEaDn9$HqqfIYQVw7g2ITH7IzK/SnCXBnKJW9wQTjSiJ16BGogkWFh89iC2/SjEY/OEXNrB/YHGI66R.wjwgg5n.2R5P0"
    }, 
    {
        "email": "xvc@yahoo.com", 
        "id": 17, 
        "isActive": null, 
        "password": "$6$rounds=94664$A/yXLhEW57Sd3ymD$unFuK75sG6jbvH9b2eQTcnIIjYi16NmSCPSxgPR7noE.JSmZDCtvxctY1s9t69nRj5IZMviPEhopnci9CpBaX/"
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you acessing the frontend on http://127.0.0.1:5000? If not, you probably having some CrossDomain issues.

Comment: @WilliamLepinski I've covered the cross domain issue. Tomas Kirda and Anik solution were correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your returned data is array. So HTML should look something similar to this:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AController">
    <div ng-repeat="u in user">
        <p>Email is {{ u.email }}</p>
        <p>password is {{ u.password }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then, you can accept this as an answer ;). Good luck!